# onCompleteListener proceeds even if the operation is not complete

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

After user authentication, I create the user node and an `IsRegistrationCompleted` variable in the Firebase Database. I then pass the check to `EventMainActivity` where the first thing I do is check the `IsRegistrationCompleted` value.

The problem I have is that when I switch to `EventMainActivity` the system has not yet finished inserting data into FirebaseDatabase and finding no value `IsRegistrationCompleted`, the system goes into error.

This is my code:

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                                FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                                isNew = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
                                if(isNew) {
                                    prefManager.setIsFirstAccess(true);
                                    addUserToDb(user);
                                    }
                            } else {
                             ..
                            }
                           ..
                        }
                    });
        }// [END auth_with_google]
```

...

//add user in Firebase Database

```
private void addUserToDb(FirebaseUser user) {
        uid = user.getUid();
        author.setUid(uid);
        author.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        author.setFull_name(user.getDisplayName());
        author.setUrl_img_profile_large(user.getPhotoUrl().toString());

        userRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);

        userRef.setValue(author).addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    setRegistrationNotCompleted();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

//insert IsRegistrationCompleted in FirebaseDatabase

```
 private void setRegistrationNotCompleted() {

    user_registration = rootRef.child("Users_Settings").child(uid).child("IsRegistrationCompleted");

    user_registration.setValue(NOT_REG).addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {          
   startActivity(newIntent(RegActivity.this,EventMainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

At this point, entering EventMainActivity I find a java.lang.NullPointerException because it does not find the variable IsRegistrationCompleted and in fact in firebase Database the value has not been inserted yet.

//This is code when try Exception

```
 usr_registration.child(uid).child("IsRegistrationCompleted").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Boolean isRegCompleted =(Boolean)  dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    Log.d(TAG,"isRegcompleted "+isRegCompleted);//Here in the Log there is  "isRegcompleted null"
                    if (isRegCompleted.equals(false)) {
                        launchWizardReg();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: can you add the code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: this code looks fine may be when you are reading values there is some thing wrong

Comment: Thanks, I entered the code above

Comment: Did you monitor database is value inserted? Or do you missing one child node `child("Users_Settings")` in `usr_registration` where `null pointer` is thrown?

Comment: This is precisely the problem, the value is not inserted. The EventMainActivity is called in the OnCompleteListener to control the insertion.

Comment: I have explained in one of my [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee) how you can implement authentication step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the check for exist in your value event listener to avoid null values, since it may take time to set the value by firebase at the node.

```
usr_registration.child(uid).child("IsRegistrationCompleted")
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        Boolean isRegCompleted =(Boolean)  dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        Log.d(TAG,"isRegcompleted "+isRegCompleted);
                        if (isRegCompleted.equals(false)) {
                            // remember to remove the value event listener, 
                            //else it will be called again if the value changes
                            launchWizardReg();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Since you are using value event listener instead of single value event it will keep triggering if the value changes at this node, so remove the listener when the value required is available

Comment: still with the check `dataSnapshot.exists()` ?

Comment: I had forgotten to delete the listener. Now it works great, thank you!